# Casting an expression to another one

Tags: c#, generics, casting, expression, graphdiff

I have following expression

`Expression<Func<T, object>> expr1;`

Is there any way to cast it to

`Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>>`?

**[Update]**

Or create a new `Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>>` from the existing `Expression<Func<T, object>>`?

Answer (score 3):

No.  The first is a function that takes a `T` and returns an `object`.  The second one accepts a `IUpdateConfiguration<T>` and returns an `object`.  Unless the `T` is also a `IUpdateConfiguration<T>`, you cannot cast this.  If you know of a way to convert a `IUpdateConfiguration<T>` into a `T`, you can make a *new* expression, but that's different than casting.

For example, given this:

```
Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, T> expr2;
```

You can make your desired function like this:

```
Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> = 
    (IUpdateConfiguration<T> t) => expr1(expr2(t));
```

But this will have a completely different expression body than the original one.  That may or may not be a problem, depending what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: How exactly is `expr1` a function?

Comment: @Unihedron: By its declaration.  More specifically, it's expression of that function type.   Expressions are used to do reflection on abstract syntax trees and inspect the actual contents of an expression.  But the input and output types are specified in the generic parameters. `T` and `object` respectively.

Comment: Could you explain your last solution(create new expression) with an example?

Comment: @Masoud:  I provided an example of producing a new expression, and corrected a typo I made earlier.

Comment: Thanks, but I think your example has some problem(2nd piece of code ) what is expr?, I have an `Expression<Func<T, object>> expr1;` and want to create a new `Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>>`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant expr1, not expr.

Comment: Shouldn't we have an object for Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>>? I mean in 2nd piece of your code before "=" which object should we have?